# Got exception when open the product page in Magento 2.1.0

Tags: magento2

I have installed the Magento 2.1.0.
And I try to update the stock status before opening each product page in program.

The code what I used to update the stock:

```
// has $sku and quantity of product now
$stockItem = $this->_stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($sku);
if($quantity > 0){
    $stockItem->setQty($quantity);
    $stockItem->setIsInStock(true);
}else{
    $stockItem->setQty(0);
    $stockItem->setIsInStock(false);
}
$this->_stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($sku, $stockItem);
```

Suddenly I can't open the product page because of the exceptions as follow:
I don't know whether because of the update of the product stock.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\module-eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource.php on line 74

Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\module-eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource.php on line 74
#0 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\module-eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'Illegal offset ...', 'D:\\www_wamp_3.0...', 74, Array)
#1 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\module-eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Frontend\AbstractFrontend.php(232): Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource->getOptionText(Array)
#2 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\module-eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Frontend\AbstractFrontend.php(107): Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Frontend\AbstractFrontend->getOption(Array)
#3 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes.php(79): Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Frontend\AbstractFrontend->getValue(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#4 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\view\attributes.phtml(19): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes->getAdditionalData()
#5 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php.php(59): include('D:\\www_wamp_3.0...')
#6 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template.php(255): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes), 'D:/www_wamp_3.0...', Array)
#7 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template.php(279): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('D:/www_wamp_3.0...')
#8 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php(659): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#9 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(542): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#10 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(518): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('product.attribu...')
#11 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('product.attribu...')
#12 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('product.attribu...')
#13 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('product.attribu...', true)
#14 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\app\design\frontend\Smartwave\porto\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\view\details.phtml(24): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('product.attribu...')
#15 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php.php(59): include('D:\\www_wamp_3.0...')
#16 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template.php(255): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description), 'D:/www_wamp_3.0...', Array)
#17 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template.php(279): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('D:/www_wamp_3.0...')
#18 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php(659): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#19 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(542): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#20 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(518): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('product.info.de...')
#21 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('product.info.de...')
#22 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('product.info.de...')
#23 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('product.info.de...', true)
#24 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('product.info.de...')
#25 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('content')
#26 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('content')
#27 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('content')
#28 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('content', true)
#29 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('content')
#30 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main')
#31 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main')
#32 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main')
#33 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main', true)
#34 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main')
#35 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('columns')
#36 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('columns')
#37 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('columns')
#38 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('columns', true)
#39 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('columns')
#40 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main.content')
#41 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main.content')
#42 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main.content')
#43 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main.content', true)
#44 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main.content')
#45 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper')
#46 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#47 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#48 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', true)
#49 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.wrapper')
#50 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root')
#51 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#52 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#53 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root', true)
#54 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(938): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('root')
#55 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
#56 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(494): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput', Array, Array)
#57 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\View\Result\Page.php(243): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
#58 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\View\Result\Layout.php(164): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#59 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#60 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)
#61 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'renderResult', Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Array, 'result-varnish-...')
#62 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\module-page-cache\Model\Controller\Result\VarnishPlugin.php(74): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#63 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\VarnishPlugin->aroundRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#64 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'renderResult', Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Array, 'result-builtin-...')
#65 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\module-page-cache\Model\Controller\Result\BuiltinPlugin.php(67): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#66 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\BuiltinPlugin->aroundRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#67 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor.php(130): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
#68 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(139): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#69 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#70 D:\www_wamp_3.0.6\YingStyle\index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#71 {main}
```

I don't know how to solve this problem.
So I found the file AbstractSource.php on line 74.

[image]

And I change the Code:

```
//if (isset($options[$value])) {
    //return $options[$value];
//}

// new code here
if (isset($options['value'])) {
    return $options['value'];
}
```

Now I can open the product again...

But I have two questions:

1. How to solve this problem/exception in a right way? I think I can't modify the file AbstractSource.php
2. Is there other problem, if I use the code "$option['value']"?

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is related to a select element in the product page not getting the correct option values or the values you have provided are not valid option values. 
From your code it seems to be from how you are using setIsInStock. From the magento code block docs, that should be legal as the setIsInStock takes either bool or int. But from Magento Core code examples, they use int. Eg:
`setIsInStock(1)`.
You can find an example here:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1.0/dev/tests/api-functional/testsuite/Magento/ConfigurableProduct/Api/CartItemRepositoryTest.php#L220

So I suggest you change the arguments from boolean to integer: `0` for `false` and `1` for `true`.

Let me know if that solves it.

Secondly, I am curious as to why you need to do this in the first place.

Comment: I'm sorry I got the same exception...if I change the code back.                             $options['value'] back to $options[$value]

Comment: I have an another System: Inventory Management System. All the products in Magento Shop need to load the stock information from my Inventory Management System.
Everytimes before we open a product page in Magento Shop, the first step is loading the stock quantity via API of my Inventory Management System.

Comment: Can you temporarily put a try catch block around 74 and 75 and dump the values of two variables, $value and $options.